# System configuration to address poor PostgreSQL INSERT performance

Tags: postgresql, configuration, performance, postgresql-10, r, postgresql-performance

### Problem Symptom

High CPU usage by `postmaster` child process associated with client connections attempting to INSERT low-volume rows (results in rows INSERTed **25x slower** than using `COPY ... FROM STDIN` for identical rows).

### Background

**Trying to identify system/ database configuration to alleviate aforementioned poor INSERT performance.** I'm using a multi-threaded R script to process data and INSERT results back into a PostgreSQL database. I've profiled the R script to isolate performance bottleneck to the `DBI::dbBind()` calls, while using `top` to monitor the `postmaster` child process associated to the connections opened by the child R threads (see **code** below). During the INSERTs, R child processes run mostly idle (presumably waiting for return of `DBI::dbBind()` call) whereas the `postmaster` child processes consume 95-100% CPU on the cores on which they run for approximately 2-3 minutes.

### System / environment:

- postgresql version 10.3 (Fedora package 10.3-5.fc27)
- `uname -a` : `Linux localhost 4.16.6-202.fc27.x86-64 #1 SMP Wed May 2 00:09:32 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- `/proc/cpuinfo` : 16 processors (`Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1541 @ 2.10GHz`)
- `ulimit -a` :

  ```
  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
  data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
  scheduling priority             (-e) 0
  file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
  pending signals                 (-i) 515220
  max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
  max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
  open files                      (-n) 1024
  pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
  POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
  real-time priority              (-r) 0
  stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
  cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
  max user processes              (-u) 515220
  virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
  file locks                      (-x) unlimited
  ```
- `/proc/meminfo` (at arbitrary time when `postmaster` processing INSERT):

  ```
  MemTotal:         131923484 kB
  MemFree:          112894260 kB
  MemAvailable:     123181440 kB
  Buffers:             201220 kB
  Cached:            14932288 kB
  SwapCached:               0 kB
  ...
  Mlocked:                  0 kB
  SwapTotal:        201326588 kB
  SwapFree:         201326588 kB
  Dirty:                 3260 kB
  ...
  Shmem:              4251184 kB
  Slab:               1024344 kB
  SReclaimable:        658476 kB
  SUnreclaim:          365868 kB
  ...
  PageTables:           38436 kB
  ...
  CommitLimit:      267288328 kB
  Committed_AS:      35678744 kB
  VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
  VmallocUsed:              0 kB
  VmallocChunk:             0 kB
  HardwareCorrupted:        0 kB
  ...
  ShmemHugePages:           0 kB
  ShmemPmdMapped:           0 kB
  ...
  HugePages_Total:          0
  HugePages_Free:           0
  HugePages_Rsvd:           0
  HugePages_Surp:           0
  Hugepagesize:          2048 kB
  Hugetlb:                  0 kB
  ...
  ```
- Database tables in testing reside on pair of SSD drives in RAID 10 configuration, with logging and WAL on separate drives (since baseline `COPY ... FROM STDIN` has no performance issue writing --see below-- (timing also includes bash `sync` return time) and CPUs do not generally appear to wait on IO, do not believe disk performance presents the bottlneck)

### Postgres configuration:

- Following is those settings not commented-out (eg. generally non-default settings)
- Some of these may appear a bit high in attempt to identify configuration change (please feel free to note any "crazy" settings given my system -- assuming the server primarily runs as database server)

  ```
  max_connections = 20                    # (change requires restart)
  shared_buffers = 32GB                   # min 128kB
  temp_buffers = 128MB                    # min 800kB
  max_prepared_transactions = 20          # Allow 'max_connections'
  work_mem = 16MB                         # min 64kB
  max_stack_depth = 6MB                   # min 100kB
  dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is the first option
  max_wal_size = 5GB
  checkpoint_flush_after = 1MB            # measured in pages, 0 disables
  deadlock_timeout = 15s
  max_locks_per_transaction = 2096        # min 10
  ```
- Also (temporarily) tried the following in `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service.d/10-postgresql-unlimited.conf` to no effect (actually a small degradation of performance): [**WARNING** For casual readers, the following settings are **NOT** recommended for use]

  ```
  # DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION (or elsewise)
  [Service]
  LimitDATA=infinity
  LimitFSIZE=infinity
  LimitLOCKS=infinity
  LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
  LimitMSGQUEUE=infinity
  LimitNPROC=infinity
  LimitNOFILE=infinity
  LimitSIGPENDING=infinity
  ```

### Database profile:

- Database cluster only has one user, and accessed generally by multi-threaded processes (between 1 and 3 threads used for testing, but up to 16 expected for automated processes and an additional 3-4 connections for administrators).
- Testing database initialized with table definitions, but no rows. Table definitions include 28 partitioned tables (using [Declarative Partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html)) that lack trigger functions and only have limited foreign keys or constraints/ indices.
- Each partitioned table has 180 partitions and between 42 and 81 columns (of `double precision` type).

  **NB**: While these are wider tables than ideal and have more partitions than recommended, I have attempted to reduce the number of columns to 12 and the number of partitions to 30 and see ratable poor INSERT performance.

### Code (R):

- Currently based on PostgreSQL ODBC driver (only one I could get working with multi-line prepared statements)

  ```
  library(odbc); 
  cdb <- DBI::dbConnect(drv=odbc::odbc(),driver="PostgreSQL",...);
  on.exit({DBI::dbDisconnect(cdb);}, add=TRUE);
  DBI::dbBegin(cdb);
  sth <- DBI::dbSendStatement(cdb,paste(rep("INSERT INTO <table> (<col_1>,...,<col_n>) VALUES (?,...,?);",100),collapse=""));   # Bind up to 8,000 placeholders at a time (ref in source?) -- use 100 multi-line statements in this example
  DBI::dbBind(sth,bvallist);   # Here, 'bvallist' is a list of values to bind in the multi-line prepared statement -- have tested and checked values in database are correct after INSERT
  num_recs <- DBI::dbGetRowsAffected(sth);
  DBI::dbClearResult(sth);
  DBI::dbCommit(cdb);
  ```

  - **NB** Have also used the following with similar performance: (A) prepared statements with only one INSERT (both in `odbc` and `RPostgres` drivers) as well as (B) assemble multi-line INSERT SQL string without use of prepared statements.

### Performance reports:

#### *Baseline*

- Based on `COPY ... FROM STDIN` -- a simple bash script containing the following command (one for each of the 28 tables): `cat <tablename>.out | psql -c 'COPY <tablename> FROM STDIN;'`
- INSERTed 11,117 rows into each of the 28 partitioned tables in 14sec => 22,234 rec/sec (or 4.5e-5 sec/rows)
- `vmstat -wt 1` information for `COPY ... FROM STDIN` (CPU info based on 16 processors):

  ```
  procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- --------cpu-------- -----timestamp-----
  r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs  us  sy  id  wa  st                 EST
  2  0            0    113563384       200600     15965816    0    0     0   696 4178  1518  14   1  85   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:19
  2  0            0    113562280       200600     15967184    0    0     0  1483 4781  1727  14   1  84   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:20
  3  0            0    113564520       200604     15962952    0    0     0  1123 4847  1790  15   2  83   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:21
  3  0            0    113565664       200604     15962020    0    0     0   800 4512  1646  15   2  84   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:22
  >>>>>>>> START: COPY ... FROM STDIN bash script (Tue Nov 27 14:29:23 EST 2018)
  3  0            0    113566992       200604     15960036    0    0     0   760 4730  1655  14   2  84   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:23
  3  1            0    113551160       200604     15961608    0    0     0  9704 5271  5025  15   3  82   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:24
  3  0            0    113548176       200604     15966864    0    0     0  8764 6269  6335  19   3  77   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:25
  3  0            0    113552104       200604     15969684    0    0     0  7744 6331  5648  19   3  77   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:26
  1  0            0    113521248       200604     15975508    0    0     0  8624 3717  5478   9   2  89   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:27
  2  0            0    113535536       200604     15976840    0    0     0 12563 4982  8784  11   3  86   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:28
  3  0            0    113535640       200604     15978772    0    0     0 11223 5473  6182  12   3  84   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:29
  2  0            0    113533576       200604     15977312    0    0     0 11180 5032  6443  12   3  85   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:30
  2  0            0    113534384       200604     15978180    0    0     0 11169 4961  6511  12   3  86   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:31
  2  0            0    113504656       200604     16004428    0    0     0 32691 4551 13584  10   3  84   2   0 2018-11-27 14:29:32
  2  0            0    113486672       200604     16023572    0    0     0 26133 4387  8803  10   3  86   2   0 2018-11-27 14:29:33
  4  0            0    113459744       200604     16033296    0    0     0 12535 5709  8188  17   3  80   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:34
  1  0            0    113444128       200604     16057612    0    0     0 78953 8980 10186  12   4  82   2   0 2018-11-27 14:29:35
  1  1            0    113415520       200604     16087380    0    0     0 23640 5576  8781  15   3  80   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:36
  3  0            0    113400864       200604     16108080    0    0     0 14733 3348 10182   6   2  90   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:37
  <<<<<<<< END  : COPY ... FROM STDIN bash script (Tue Nov 27 14:29:37 EST 2018)
  1  0            0    113393552       200632     16127372    0    0     0 56640 4456  4481   4   3  93   1   0 2018-11-27 14:29:38
  0  1            0    113392368       200632     16127680    0    0     0  1688 2446  1406   2   1  96   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:39
  1  0            0    113391032       200632     16128472    0    0     0  1616 2372  1396   2   1  97   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:40
  0  0            0    113389376       200632     16128440    0    0     0  1896 2474  1402   2   1  96   0   0 2018-11-27 14:29:41
  ```

#### *Current*

- When binding a multi-line prepared statement within a single transaction block (see **code**), it takes 390 sec to INSERT the same rows into each of the 28 partitioned tables for total throughput of 9 rows/ sec (compared to the 22,234 rows/sec in the baseline)
- The max/avg/min values from `vmstat -wt 1` during the INSERT resulting from `DBI::dbBind()` appear as follows:

  ```
  procs -----------------------memory---------------------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- --------cpu--------
  r  b         swpd         free         buff        cache   si   so    bi    bo    in    cs  us  sy  id  wa  st     
  6  1            0    112348416       200092     15661572    0    0     0 10090 12259 37796  32   3  81   4   0   # MAX
  3  0            0    111860781       199437     15608955    0    0     0  1708  5658  6371  21   1  78   0   0   # AVG
  3  0            0    111353344       199372     15572860    0    0     0   184  4115  1602  17   0  67   0   0   # MIN
  ```

### Other notes:

- Performance unaffected when running single or multiple R child threads (ie. one or multiple database client connections).
- Have tried to use `RPostgres`, `RPostgreSQL`, and `odbc` R packages as database drivers (while slight performance differences exist among the drivers, no implementation-specific artifacts appear to contribute significantly to the processing time).
- <strike>Working on EXPLAIN ANALYZE of SQL, but</strike> welcome thoughts ahead of time on potential kernel settings/ database configuration/ SystemD settings/ etc.

Thank you in advance.

### Update (2018.11.28)

- Created an SQL flat file with the INSERT statements produced by the R script (placed the statements within a `BEGIN ... COMMIT` transaction block) and loaded using `psql -f <file>.sql` -- no performance improvement.
- Ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE VERBOSE` on single INSERT, with following output:

  ```
  Insert on <tablename>  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=1952) (actual time=0.074..0.074 rows=0 loops=1)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=1952) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=1 loops=1)
           Output: <row data>
  Planning time: 0.303 ms
  Trigger RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_274329 for constraint <foreign_key_constraint_name> on <child_tablename>: time=0.071 calls=1
  Execution time: 13.345 ms
  ```

Comment: If I read this correctly the time is mostly dominated by the FK „trigger“, did you try how fast it is without this constraint?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I noticed that as well, but wasn't certain if the FK checks represented per-statement or per-row costs. After making the SQL statement change as noted in the self-answer and re-running for a bulk INSERT of 4,190 rows on a  partitioned table, I found that the cost increased per-row, but not linearly. I was able to INSERT the 4,190 rows with a total 125ms cost (involving the 180 child tables). I have a bit more profiling to do (and yet to see if the cost is manageable at scale) to see if FK constraint check optimization worthwhile. All the best.

Comment: Are all foreign key columns indexed? The usual reason for slow RI_ConstraintTriggers is that the FK columns isn't indexed and every check is doing a Seq Scan on that table rather than an index lookup

Comment: I believe so (the two foreign key columns are the primary key of the foreign table, so I believe the primary key automatically indexes the two columns as a group -- if not, I may then need to add an index). The foreign key constraint references both columns (no partial indices or per-column indices are defined). Is there a way to determine whether the planner selects a sequential scan vs. index lookup?

Answer (score 2):

A change to the prepared SQL statement resulted in a six-fold improvement.

SQL changed from:

```
    INSERT INTO <table> (<col_1>,...,<col_n>) VALUES (?,...,?);
    ...
    INSERT INTO <table> (<col_1>,...,<col_n>) VALUES (?,...,?);
```

to:

```
    INSERT INTO <table> (<col_1>,...,<col_n>) VALUES
    (?,...,?),
    ...
    (?,...,?);
```

In other words, I collapsed the multiple INSERT statements into a single statement, which reduced the time from 390 sec to 66 sec, or 56 rows/sec. While still on the slow side, will need to re-profile the execution to see if the remaining latency is application- or database-related.